# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException

Tags: c#, smtpclient, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am trying to understand why do I get the following error:

> 2016-02-05 12:04:16.0776 [89] FATAL ExceptionHandling.Models.EmailService+d__1.MoveNext - Error occurred while sending an Email. - System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.
>      at System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.OperationStarted()
>      at System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperation.CreateOperation(Object userSuppliedState, SynchronizationContext syncContext)
>      at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendAsync(MailMessage message, Object userToken)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendAsync(MailMessage message, Object userToken)
>      at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendMailAsync(MailMessage message)
>      at Kubra.Common.ExceptionHandling.Models.EmailService.d__1.MoveNext()

When I run this localy, it generates the email, when I run it on my dev environment, again no problem.  I move it to my test environment and all of a sudden I get the async problem.  The configuration is the same between all 3 environments and I am trying to understand the underlying problem so that I can address it.

The code where the error occurs:

```
public class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    private static readonly ILogger Logger = LogFactory.GetLogger();
    private readonly string _host;
    private readonly int _port;
    private readonly NetworkCredential _credentials;
    private readonly bool _enableSsl;

    public EmailService(EmailConfiguration emailSettings)
    {
        _host = emailSettings.Host;
        _port = emailSettings.PortNumber;
        _credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailSettings.Username, emailSettings.Password);
        _enableSsl = emailSettings.UseSsl;
    }

    public async Task<bool> SendEmail(EmailTemplate email)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = _host,
                Port = _port,
                Credentials = _credentials,
                EnableSsl = _enableSsl
            })
            {
                client.Host = _host;
                client.Port = _port;
                client.Credentials = _credentials;
                client.EnableSsl = _enableSsl;
                await client.SendMailAsync(email.Message);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Fatal(ex, "Error occurred while sending an Email.");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Code that calls the class:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    try
    {
        var subject = "Server Error on MVC CSR: " + Environment.MachineName;
        var email = new ErrorEmail(subject, "", serverError.StackTrace);
        _emailService = new EmailService(new ConfigEmail());
        Task.Run(() => { _emailService.SendEmail(email); }).Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Fatal(ex, "Error occurred while sending e-mail");
    }
}
```

Comment: on the Dev environment vs the Test environment I would make sure that you have the same .net framework / assemblies that are installed on the Dev machine installed on the Test Machine also if you are using any .dll's that need to have `CopyLocal = false` that are not on the Test target maching.. change those properties to `=true` also if this is a web interface can you show the header of the .aspx file..? there is a property that you can type in the page header `Async=true`

Comment: @MethodMan this is happening in Global.asax.cs in Application_Error() method

Comment: can you show the .aspx section where you have `<%@ Page.....` you should have a property of `Async=true`

Comment: @MethodMan I am not sure what you are referring to, I have a controller that throws an error and then when the error is thrown it gets redirected to Application_Error() by MVC5 (C#) code.  In here I make my call.  This method resides in Global.asax.cs.  So I am not sure whant .aspx page you are referring to as none of them are involved in this scenario.

Comment: sorry I didn't realize this was MCV5 I thought it was standard .aspx page file that you were using.. I still think that you have dll difference from dev to test

Comment: I am having this same issue, have you figured it out.